# how to change this sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.tbh_table 
WHERE TopicID IN (
  SELECT value 
  FROM dbo.fn_split('19,',')
)
```

I have to change above query to execute result like below

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.tbh_table 
WHERE TopicID LIKE '%19,%'
```

My topicID values are like this 15,19,12,1
But split will give values are 15 19 12 1. because of which i am not able to execute the query.

any guidance will help

Comment: Do you own this database? Maybe now would be a good time to normalise it and have a link between the dbo.tbh_table and the Topic table. That way you can use set theory. Is the column in question (dbo.tbh_table.TopicID) a VARCHAR?

Comment: There's a related (but not duplicate) question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609657/sql-server-replacing-single-quotes-and-using-in/1609674#1609674

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `fn_split` is a table valued function (`TVF`), returning a `TABLE (value INT)`, use this:

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    dbo.tbh_table t
CROSS APPLY
        dbo.fn_split(TopicID) split
WHERE   split.value = 19
```

Comment: upvoted. I didn't know about cross apply. This is a sqlserver specific thing, right?

Answer (score 0):

You could add your IDs to a table variable and then join with the table variable to determine if TopicID was in the table variable.

```
DECLARE @DesiredIDs TABLE (
   DesiredID INT
)

INSERT INTO @DesiredIDs (DesiredID) Values (15)
INSERT INTO @DesiredIDs (DesiredID) Values (19)
INSERT INTO @DesiredIDs (DesiredID) Values (12)
INSERT INTO @DesiredIDs (DesiredID) Values (1)

select * from tbh_table t 
left join @DesiredIDs d on d.DesiredID = t.TopicID 
where d.DesiredID is not null
```

Comment: If I am reading the question right, his question isn't "how do I match 15 or 19 or 12 or 1" but "how do I match 19 to a topicId comma-delimited string, given that I have a table function to separate the string". So your solution doesn't work. Plus not needing a desiredIds table is precisely what the IN clause was invented for.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.tbh_table 
WHERE 19 IN ( 
  SELECT value 
  FROM dbo.fn_split(TopicId,',')
)
```